# How to set our p and q values manually?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I have the C# code that does encryption but I want to give my own p and q, how can I edit it? When I try to give for instance; p=11 q=5 manually, it won't let me edit inside the method.

```
private static RSAParameters Create(byte[] p, byte[] q, byte[] exponent, byte[] modulus)
{
    var addlParameters = GetFullPrivateParameters(
        p: new BigInteger(CopyAndReverse(p)),
        q: new BigInteger(CopyAndReverse(q)),
        e: new BigInteger(CopyAndReverse(exponent)),
        modulus: new BigInteger(CopyAndReverse(modulus)));

    return new RSAParameters
    {
        P = p,
        Q = q,
        Exponent = exponent,
        Modulus = modulus,
        D = addlParameters.D,
        DP = addlParameters.DP,
        DQ = addlParameters.DQ,
        InverseQ = addlParameters.InverseQ,
    };
}

private static RSAParameters GetFullPrivateParameters(BigInteger p, BigInteger q, BigInteger e, BigInteger modulus)
{
    var n = p * q;
    var phiOfN = n - p - q + 1; // OR: (p - 1) * (q - 1);

    var d = ModInverse(e, phiOfN);
    //Assert.Equal(1, (d * e) % phiOfN);

    var dp = d % (p - 1);
    var dq = d % (q - 1);

    var qInv = ModInverse(q, p);
    //Assert.Equal(1, (qInv * q) % p);

    return new RSAParameters
    {
        D = CopyAndReverse(d.ToByteArray()),
        DP = CopyAndReverse(dp.ToByteArray()),
        DQ = CopyAndReverse(dq.ToByteArray()),
        InverseQ = CopyAndReverse(qInv.ToByteArray()),
    };
}
```

**[EDIT]**
I changed the `Create()` like below;

```
  private static RSAParameters Create(byte[] p, byte[] q, byte[] exponent, byte[] modulus)
        {
            //set number to byte array
            int intValueP = 51;
            int intValueQ = 7;
            byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValueP);
            byte[] intBytes2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValueQ);
            var addlParameters = GetFullPrivateParameters(
                p: new BigInteger(CopyAndReverse(intBytes)),
                q: new BigInteger(CopyAndReverse(intBytes2)),
                e: new BigInteger(CopyAndReverse(exponent)),
                modulus: new BigInteger(CopyAndReverse(modulus)));
```

However it gave me the error(see picture)[image]

The method gives error saying there is a problem during conversion, Can you please help

```
public static BigInteger ModInverse(BigInteger a, BigInteger n)
    {
        BigInteger t = 0, nt = 1, r = n, nr = a;

        if (n < 0)
        {
            n = -n;
        }

        if (a < 0)
        {
            a = n - (-a % n);
        }

        while (nr != 0)
        {
            var quot = r / nr;

            var tmp = nt; nt = t - quot * nt; t = tmp;
            tmp = nr; nr = r - quot * nr; r = tmp;
        }

        if (r > 1) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(a) + " is not convertible.");
        if (t < 0) t = t + n;
        return t;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're seeing. `RSAParameters` is a [public struct](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/3b1eaf5203992df69de44c783a3eda37d3d4cd10/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rsa.cs#L25). Can't you just make one?

Comment: @John I don't understand, can you please show me what you mean

Comment: You seem to have it in your code `new RSAParameters { P = p`, etc. - what is the problem you're seeing? _"When I try to give for instance; p=11 q=5 manually, it won't let me edit inside the method."_ - I don't understand this. Why can't you edit it?

Comment: Do you want to set the values of p and q inside GetFullPrivateParameters and be able to access those particular values in Create?

Comment: @John p and q are byte arrays and they are belong to the library wherever I try to give my value it gives error

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code where you're setting the value, and provide details of what the error is?

Comment: @Fernando if possible yes, if not I want to edit inside the Create() method

Comment: @John I used to do `var p = new BigInteger(61);` for instance, but I don't know how to perform same logic with p which is a byte array

Comment: The [BigInteger documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger) tells you what to do. There is a `ToByteArray` method to convert a BigInteger to a byte array and there is `new BigInteger(byte[])` constructor to convert a byte array to a BigInteger.

Comment: @BB if you want to set the values in Create, you have to set them to the binary representation of the number you want, for example p = BitConverter.GetBytes(11);

Comment: @Fernando I set number to byte array like this; `int intValueP = 51;
            byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValueP);
            var addlParameters = GetFullPrivateParameters(
                p: new BigInteger(CopyAndReverse(intBytes)),`

Comment: What error do you get? Make sure to use your values in the return as well.

Comment: @Fernando please check I edited my post

Comment: @John I added more information in detail can you check now please

Comment: The exception is thrown by your code after it checked whether "r > 1". I don't see what this has to do with your original problem.

Comment: Why do you expect r <= 1 after the while?  In the while it always holds the value of nr before it turns to 0, which its more than likely to always be > 1.

Comment: The smallest size that any .NET RSA class will accept for import is a 384-bit modulus. So each of p and q need to be bigger than 2**191. 11 is 188 bits short, 5 is 189 bits short.

Comment: @bartonjs I see, thank you

Comment: @bartonjs but I can not give 512 bit in this structure, big int takes a method as you can see, which takes byte array